# Get request Headers always empty

Tags: c#, api, basic-authentication, restsharp

I'm trying to consume my own Webservice written in C#, protected with basic authentication.

The problem is that when I call the Webservice using Postman, it works fine, in particular `actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization` contains the authentication header as shown in the screenshot below:

[image: visual studio screen called by postman]

[image: visual studio screen called by postman]

The problem is that when I try to call the same Webservice from code the headers are always null.

Initially, I have tried  with HttpWebRequest as I use to, with the following code:

```
var encoded = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(username + ":" + password));
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(completeUrl);
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);
...
request.GetResponse();
```

I've tried minor things I read in other StackOverflow threads such as add the header in other ways like request.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization], using WebHeaderCollection instead of directly adding the headers to the request. I also made a test setting the user agent, changing the AutomaticDecompression type without success.

The oddity is that I still get null header using the postman's autogenerated code (that uses RestSharp)

```
var client = new RestClient(completeUrl);
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
            request.AddHeader("postman-token", "0e75d22d-0bd4-ea1d-b53d-d4a6c3edb564");
            request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
            request.AddHeader("authorization", "Basic Q0RCV0RNOkNEQldETQ==");
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

What could be the difference between the request manually generated from code and the Postman's one?
Should I have to add other Headers in order to get the Webservice reached?

Comment: You can [edit your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63113884/trying-to-use-httpwebrequest-to-consume-get-api-with-basic-authentication-but-g) to add details, please don't repeat questions.

Comment: Do you get the same Base64String in your encoding?